# How to use mochawesome and mocha-sonarqube-report in a single command?

Tags: node.js, sonarqube, mocha.js, nyc, mochawesome

I have the following script in my package.json file to check the code coverage of the UT:

```
"coverage": "nyc --reporter=lcov --reporter=cobertura mocha ./test/apis_new/* --reporter mocha-sonarqube-reporter --reporter-options output=xunit.xml mocha ./test/apis_new/* --reporter mochawesome --exit"
```

When I run the above command, only **mochawesome-report** folder is getting generated but there is no such file as **xunit.xml**.

If I run the bellow command where I have changed the order of mochawesome and sonarqube, **xunit.xml** is geting generated but not **mochawesome-report** folder:

```
"coverage": "nyc --reporter=lcov --reporter=cobertura mocha ./test/apis_new/* --reporter mochawesome mocha ./test/apis_new/* --reporter mocha-sonarqube-reporter --reporter-options output=xunit.xml --exit"
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is this the right way to use both together in a single script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively, mocha supports only one reporter, so all behaves as expected only one of reporters (possibly first) is used.

Check out [mocha-multi-reporters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-multi-reporters). I use it to generate `xunit` and `spec` output.